# MongoDB multiple nested groups

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents in mongodb like this

```
{
  _id: "5cfed55974c7c52ecc33ada8",
  name: "Garona",
  realm: "Blackrock",
  faction: "Horde",
  race: "Orc",
  class: "Rogue",
  guild: "",
  level: 33,
  lastSeen: "2019-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
  __v: 0
},
{
  _id: "5cfed55974c7c52ecc33ade8",
  name: "Muradin",
  realm: "Alleria",
  faction: "Alliance",
  race: "Dwarf",
  class: "Warrior",
  guild: "Stormstout Brewing Co",
  level: 42,
  lastSeen: "2019-06-11T00:00:00.000Z",
  __v: 0
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is to group by a fields and get a sum of it. So far I figured it out to do it for one field at once like so

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      classes: '1',
      class: '$class'
    },
    total: { $sum: 1 }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$_id.classes',
    total: { $sum: '$total' },
    classes: {
      $push: {
        class: '$_id.class',
        total: '$total'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which produces something like this

```
{
  _id: "1",
  total: 40,
  classes: [
    {
      class: "Warrior",
      total: 17
    },
    {
      class: "Rogue",
      total: 23
    }
}
```

But I want to do it for more than one field at once, so that I can get an output like this.

```
{
  _id: "1",
  total: 40,
  classes: [
    {
      class: "Warrior",
      total: 17
    },
    {
      class: "Rogue",
      total: 23
    },
  factions: [
    {
      faction: "Alliance",
      total: 27
    },
    {
      faction: "Horde",
      total: 13
    }
}
```

No I'm wondering if it is even possible to do it in one query in an easy way or if I would be better to do a seperate query for each field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the [$facet aggregation stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

> Processes multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents. Each sub-pipeline has its own field in the output document where its results are stored as an array of documents.

I only slightly modified your original pipeline, and then just copied it for the 'factions' field.

The last 3 stages in my solution aren't really necessary, they just clean up the output a little bit.

You can probably take it from here, good luck.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "classes": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$class",
            total: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            total: {
              $sum: "$total"
            },
            "classes": {
              $push: {
                class: "$_id",
                total: "$total"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "factions": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$faction",
            total: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            total: {
              $sum: "$total"
            },
            "factions": {
              $push: {
                faction: "$_id",
                total: "$total"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$classes"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$factions"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "classes._id": 0,
      "factions._id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "classes": {
      "classes": [
        {
          "class": "Warrior",
          "total": 1
        },
        {
          "class": "Rogue",
          "total": 1
        }
      ],
      "total": 2
    },
    "factions": {
      "factions": [
        {
          "faction": "Alliance",
          "total": 1
        },
        {
          "faction": "Horde",
          "total": 1
        }
      ],
      "total": 2
    }
  }
]
```